# Password Protect viewing the account page

Tags: 7, users

I want to make the user re-enter their password to view their account page similar to how some sites make you re-enter it to edit settings, I want to make them enter it to view their account.  Does anyone know if there is a module capable of doing this? I tried the [Protected Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/protected_pages) Module with a password for /user and it put me in a redirect loop however it wasn't really what I need anyway.

I could also do it with a hook however I load and save the user object in a number of other places and it can't affect them.